# Get month list starting from a given month and ending to another?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, range, increment

Given two integers (each that represent months in a year), I need to produce an array of integers that represents the inclusive range of months between them.

To get the month numbers between December and February, the input is:

```
$start = 12;
$finish = 2;
```

The expected output contains three elements: 12, 1, and 2  (because December, January, then February)

I have tried using `$arraylist = range($start, $finish);`, but when the `$start` value is greater than the `$finish` value, then the output is an incorrect descending range like this: <s>`[12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`</s>

Here are some more input-output examples:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------------+
| $start | $finish |        $output        |
+--------+---------+-----------------------|
|    3   |    11   | [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] |
+--------+---------+-----------------------|
|   11   |     3   |     [11,12,1,2,3]     |
+--------+---------+-----------------------|
|    3   |     3   |           [3]         |
+--------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Where does the `1` come from in your desired output?

Comment: @Nick I created an array for number of months, with method 2 number for the input, if input start is 11 and finish is 3 it will come out [11,12,1,2,3]

Comment: what is the expected result when the start is 3 and the finish is 3?  One element or thirteen elements?

Comment: @mickmackusa bcs is number of months i hope return output is 3 if we input 3 and 3 as range

Comment: Although the answers provided were spot on for the question asked, none of this addresses any months ranges that spans more than two years. Just a heads up for anyone with a similar problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: @ToddBFisher Because 12 months is only for one year and 1 range array, I don't need it for 2 years, after all the input is only from two variables, if 2 years is possible maybe we need more input data

Comment: The quality of the input is insufficient to express multiple years -- since the input value are expected to be between 1 and 12.  If you (or anyone else) has different question requirements, feel free to ask a new question and state how a new technique is required to extend the functionality of the solutions here.  It is important that the scope of this question not spiral into oblivion.  This is a good, narrow question and I hope it remains this way.  I am saddened by the fact that this question received DVs and got closed -- I think there is too much negativity in this community.

Comment: @mickmackusa because I always think positively, maybe they don't know the meaning of my question because I wrote it messily, thank you for providing solutions and fixing my questions, I hope they are helped by my questions

Comment: @ IlhamRiski I think this question is perfectly fine and has correct scope for your needs, and I see nothing wrong with that. I was just thinking of the people that will read this question in the future and might blindly copy it without verifying that it meets their needs as well. Thank you @mickmackusa for adding further clarification with your comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be much less complicated than decrementing everything, using modulus/arithmetic, and bumping numbers into the preferred value.

- Loop while the two numbers are not the same.
- If the incremented number is increased to more than 12, reset it to 1.
- To make the range inclusive, push the finish number into the array.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nIMcm))

```
$array = [];
while ($start != $finish) {
    if ($start > 12) {
        $start = 1;
    }
    $array[] = $start++;  // increment AFTER pushing into the array
}
$array[] = $finish;
var_export($array);
```

I think this is less cryptic to read.

Inputs/Outputs:

```
11, 3: [11, 12, 1, 2, 3]

3, 11: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

3, 3: [3]
```

---

p.s. The following functional style doesn't feel silly either. There will be either 1 or 3 function calls, but again I think it is pretty easy to read AND there is no loop, no temporary variables, and no incrementing/decrementing.

Since the volume of data is guaranteed to be small, performance probably doesn't even factor in (no human is going to notice a difference in performance between an techniques on this page).  It would be better to select a technique that is readable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IWkUd))

```
$array = $start > $finish
    ? array_merge(range($start, 12), range(1, $finish))
    : range($start, $finish);
```

---

p.p.s. A final consideration... If anyone would prefer to handle the month logic with a DateTime technique, this would also be sensible and may open a door to extending the functionality further (if the task should ever need it).  The drawback is that this technique has the most overhead because it is instantiating objects to work with.

To make the output array include the last month, an easy solution is to add 1 to the finish.  If the `$begin` value is less than the `$finish` value, then we will push the value into next year by adding 12.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/C9SBp))

```
$begin = 11;
$finish = 3;

$period = new DatePeriod(
    DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $begin),
    new DateInterval('P1M'),
    DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $finish + ($begin > $finish ? 13 : 1))
);

foreach ($period as $obj) {
    $array[] = $obj->format('n');
}

var_export($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use modulo 12 arithmetic. First convert `$start` and `$finish` to the range 0-11 by subtracting one, then increment `$start` and push to the array (converting back to the range 1-12 as you do) until `$start == $finish`:

```
$start = 12;
$finish = 2;

$arraylist = array();
$start = --$start;
$finish = --$finish;
while ($start != $finish) {
    $arraylist[] = ++$start;
    $start = $start % 12;
}
$arraylist[] = ++$start;
print_r($arraylist);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uplON)